# Client side JavaScript example which would authentication to AD FS version 3.0 (on prem)

Tags: adal, adfs3.0, adal.js

I am looking for a simple client side JavaScript example to authenticate against AD FS version 3.0 (on prem).

I have so far attempted to utilize ADAL.js. However, I have learned from my research that this doesn't function properly due to ADFS version 3.0 not having the oAuth2 implicit grant functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - ADFS 3.0 only supports Authorisation Code Grant for confidential clients (web API).

You could do this natively because ultimately it's all REST.

The PowerShell side of ADFS is [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).